# When Using STUnion to construct a polygon, is it faster to do it on code or let the Database handle it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlgeography

I was just wondering which is faster:

1. Constructing a wkt polygon using SQLGeography's STUnion method.
2. Constructing a wkt polygon using the STUnion method built into MS SQL Server.

I only ask because I wanted to be sure.  I'm assuming that if I went with 2, querying and constantly updating the database would increase the amount of time it takes to process/create the data.  This would be through one connection so there wouldn't be a need to reconnect every time something needed to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some benchmarks and constructing the polygons using the STUnion method in C# was at least twice as fast.